# C# Async UDP listener SocketException

Tags: c#, asynchronous, udp, socketexception

I have a pretty simple Asynchronous UDP listener, setup as a service, and it's been working quite well for awhile now, but it recently crashed on a SocketException `An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`.  I have three questions:

1. What's causing this?  (I didn't think UDP sockets had a connection)
2. How can I duplicate it, for testing purposes?
3. How can I cleanly handle the exception, so everything will continue to work?

My code looks something like the following:

```
private Socket udpSock;
private byte[] buffer;
public void Starter(){
    //Setup the socket and message buffer
    udpSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    udpSock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 12345));
    buffer = new byte[1024];

    //Start listening for a new message.
    EndPoint newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    udpSock.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, udpSock);
}

private void DoReceiveFrom(IAsyncResult iar){
    try{
        //Get the received message.
        Socket recvSock = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
        EndPoint clientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        int msgLen = recvSock.EndReceiveFrom(iar, ref clientEP);
        byte[] localMsg = new byte[msgLen];
        Array.Copy(buffer, localMsg, msgLen);

        //Start listening for a new message.
        EndPoint newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        udpSock.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, udpSock);

        //Handle the received message
        Console.WriteLine("Recieved {0} bytes from {1}:{2}",
                          msgLen,
                          ((IPEndPoint)clientEP).Address,
                          ((IPEndPoint)clientEP).Port);
        //Do other, more interesting, things with the received message.
    } catch (ObjectDisposedException){
        //expected termination exception on a closed socket.
        // ...I'm open to suggestions on a better way of doing this.
    }
}
```

The exception is being thrown at the recvSock.EndReceiveFrom() line.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [this forum thread](http://microsoft.public.win32.programmer.networks.narkive.com/RlxW2V6m/udp-comms-and-connection-reset-problem), it seems that the UDP socket is also receiving ICMP messages and throwing exceptions when they are received.  Maybe this is great for low level status updates, but I found it annoying.

First, define the magic number

```
public const int SIO_UDP_CONNRESET = -1744830452;
```

Then set the low level io control to ignore these messages:

```
var client = new UdpClient(endpoint);
client.Client.IOControl(
    (IOControlCode)SIO_UDP_CONNRESET, 
    new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
    null
);
```

Comment: Great Man! Hi had same problem of receiving ICMP messages and throwing exceptions when they are received. Which is solved by your coding trick!

Comment: @Kyle, I finally got around to fully testing this!  It would seem this was the actual root cause of the exception.  For reference, I ended  up using both your answer and Jim's, so that even if there is an exception, the listener gets restarted.

Comment: Broken Link. This answer should be changed to either update the link or include the information that the link pointed to.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen that error with UDP if a packet is somehow truncated or otherwise not completely delivered.  At least, I *think* that's what happens.  I've never been able to duplicate it reliably.

I would suggest that you catch the `SocketException`, log it (if you want), and then dispose of that socket.  Then call `Starter` again:

```
catch (SocketException)
{
    // log error
    udpSock.Close();
    Starter();
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, but I'd still like to know what's actually causing this exception (i.e. prove what you think is correct).

Comment: @chezy525 I believe these socket exceptions usually arise from ICMP "Destination/Port/etc. unreachable" messages on your socket. How you'd get one if you're just listening, I'm not sure. Just a thought.

Comment: try enabling system.net tracing and see whats going underneath