# How to create truly connectionless UdpClient?

Tags: c#, .net-core, udpclient

My goal is to create UDP listener that handles all datagrams incoming to specified port, regardless of its origin. Then it responds to that origin with some message.

```
public void StartListening(int port = 13000)
{
    ListenerPort = port;
    udpClient = new UdpClient(ListenerPort);

    udpClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(handleIncomingMessages), null);
}

private void handleIncomingMessages(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var receivedData = udpClient.EndReceive(ar, ref senderIpEndPoint);
    //[...]
    udpClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(handleIncomingMessages), null);
}
```

Everything worked fine until I turned off one of those "origins". After a few seconds my listener caught `SocketException`.

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I always thought UDP is a connectionless protocol, yet it seems UdpClient tracks somehow that remote host is available. Is there some standard, .NET Core way I could disable this?

EDIT:

Here is error stack trace:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
  Source=System.Net.Sockets
  StackTrace:
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceiveFrom(IAsyncResult asyncResult, EndPoint& endPoint)
   at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult, IPEndPoint& remoteEP)
   at NetworkController.UDP.NetworkManager.handleIncomingMessages(IAsyncResult ar) in [...]
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback()
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.<>c.<Complete>b__15_0(Object s)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
```

Comment: That error message is translated from Windows API error code, so it is generic for both TCP and UDP. However, it alone does not mean UDP is connection oriented.

Comment: @LexLi That still leaves the question, where does it come from? It should be completely transparent to the UdpClient if one of the "origins" doesn't live anymore.

Comment: Not precisely a duplicate, but also [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30749423/4137916).

Comment: The call stack and .NET Core source code should lead you to the actual cause of the exception. Not much to discuss further without such details.

Comment: @LexLi hi, thank you for reponse. I've included stack trace in my question

Comment: There is an answer on SO suggesting "disabling exception" caused by ICMP messages. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39440399/1804027 Unfortunately there is no such thing as SIO_UDP_CONNRESET in .net core

Comment: I've finaly fixed it thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9125485/1804027